# How to make sidebar line up with footer?

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer, sidebar

I have a problem with my sidebar. The design I'm coding right now has the sidebar slightly overlapping the header of the site - intentionally. The problem however, is that I might use the wrong method to do it.

The sidebar is supposed to be lining up with the footer, but since i'm using:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    position: relative;
    left: 690px;
    bottom: 125px;
```

If I don't use these lines the sidebar matches up, but I can't find any other way to do it.

There's another problem which shows up when Content gets added, the sidebar will automatically bring all the sidebar-content down with the main content, though the sidebar-frame will stay at the same spot.

I've included the page in codepen if you want to take a look at it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxpJa

Thank you for your help, Michael :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
position: relative;
left: 690px;
bottom: 125px;
```

And add:

```
float: right;
margin-top: -65px; /* adjust to your needs */
```

Then clear the floated `<aside>` *right* before the closing parent `</div>` ... add:

`<br style="clear: right;" />`

[Example](http://jsbin.com/etatiy/2)

This will be more consistent across browsers and the `<aside>` lines up with the `<footer>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the sidebar is not lining up with the footer (by that I suppose you mean the footer is immediately under the sidebar with no additional spacing) is because you have positioned the sidebar relatively to its parent container. The height of the sidebar is therefore still the same as before, and will not take into account that it should be taller because you have moved it upwards.

Try floating the wrapping parent to the right, and then giving the `#sidebar` element a negative top margin.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
   float: right; 
}
#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    margin-top: -125px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #282828;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guys comments, I did actually try this method, but changed it to the current one because it gives me another problem - The content-wrapper is also supposed to align with the footer, but whenever i implement float: right; to the sidebar element the content-wrapper stops right after the content.

Comment: Extra markup for clearing floats makes Baby Jesus cry.  http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: You just have to clear the float. Use `overflow: hidden`, or the clearfix method. The former may not work because you are negatively extending the top margin.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help, I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days now, couldn't find out what it was :)

Answer (score 0):

`margin-top: -125px;` instead of `bottom: 125px;`